# Generic class type usage in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I am trying to write a generic base activity, that specifies it's ViewModel type a generic parameter:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity()
```

Now I am trying to write a lazy initialized property for my ViewModel:

```
val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, getFactory()).get(T) }
```

The error that is displayed is `Type Parameter T is not an expression`

Also using `::class` or `::class.java` did not help. Can anyone explain the problem?

**EDIT:** I tried to use a reified inline function like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel?> AppCompatActivity.obtainViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(T::class.java)
}
```

And used it like this:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T> : AppCompatActivity() {
    val viewModel by lazy { obtainViewModel<T>(getFactory()) 
}
```

Now I get the error, that T cannot be used as a reified parameter.

**EDIT2:** The best solution so far seems to be this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012190/kotlin-abstract-class-with-generic-param-and-methods-which-use-type-param), but its overhead to implement the abstract token in every extending class.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more detailed? @Mango

Answer (score 2):

Your class has a type parameter `T`, which unfortunately gets erased at runtime. As a result, the call `get(T)` does not work (I guess the method expects a `Class` actually?).

You seem to have already noticed that and thus tried to fix it with encapsulating the handling into a method using `reified` type. Yet, you cannot pass `T` as a reified parameter since this type will already be erased when the `reified`-typed method is called. As a result, `obtainViewModel<T>` will not work either. What you can do, is using `T` for ordinary generic methods, which the following demonstrates:

```
class Typed<T> {
    val lazyProp by lazy {
        listOf<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to achieve the behaviour I was trying to implement?

Comment: Not that way I'm afraid. What do you think about the suggestion I just added

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Unfortunately, this would make the code I am trying to wrap away become more complicated than it was before. :/

Comment: have you found another way to do this?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones not sure if u have found the solution, but check out my suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480529/5315499

Comment: @TrungLe, that is not a true solution since you would still need to extend that Abstract Base Class. If you would still need to extend the class just to define the view model then you might as well not use generics for it instead. Just define the view model on the child class instead.

Answer (score 2):

maybe a bit late, but I guess this could be the elegant way to achieve it:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewModel>(
    private var modelClass: Class<T>) : AppCompatActivity() {

    val viewModel by lazy { 
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, getFactory()).get(modelClass) 
    }

}
```

and then

```
class SampleActivity : BaseActivity<SampleViewModel>(SampleViewModel::class.java) {
    // use viewModel from here
}
```