# Generic getter for multiple Collection in Mongo with Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, generics, kotlin

I use Kotlin and Mongo (with [KMongo](http://litote.org/kmongo/)) and I have multiple models as `UserEntity`, `MovieEntity` and so on. Each of them use a specific `Dao` class to do (actually) the same methods. Therefore, I'm trying to avoid any duplication by using a `BaseDao` which should have these methods instead.

So I pass the specific entity in the generic base as:

```
class UserDao : BaseDao<UserEntity>() { ... }
```

This base class implements the generic methods as follows:

```
open class BaseDao<T: Any>() {

    fun get(id: String): T? {
        return getCollection().findOneById(id)
    }

    fun save(entity: T): T {
        return getCollection().save(entity)
    }

    fun delete(id: String) {
        getCollection().deleteOneById(id)
    }
    ...
}
```

However, a problem occurs on `getCollection()` method:

```
private inline fun <reified T: Any> getCollection(): MongoCollection<T> {
    return MongoDb.getDatabase().getCollection<T>()
}
```

This gets a compilation error each time I call it:

```
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 
inline fun <reified T : Any> getCollection(): MongoCollection<T#1 (type parameter of app.api.db.dao.BaseDao.getCollection)>  
Please specify it explicitly.
```

I can't find the right way to do this. I already checked these threads but I didn't make it work: [Generic class type usage in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901233/generic-class-type-usage-in-kotlin) & [Kotlin abstract class with generic param and methods which use type param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012190/kotlin-abstract-class-with-generic-param-and-methods-which-use-type-param).

**Question:**

How can I achieve this generic `BaseDao` which should get any collection of each child `Dao`?

Comment: Seems you don't need `<reified T : Any>` at all. Try simply `<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use reflection as [Zigzago mentioned](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kmongo/-hCTvyoSAW0/NLJ-aq6KBAAJ) by using `KMongoUtil`:

```
protected fun getCollection(): MongoCollection<T> =
    getDaoEntityClass().let { k ->
        MongoDb.getDatabase().getCollection(
            KMongoUtil.defaultCollectionName(k), k.java)
    }

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun getDaoEntityClass(): KClass<T>
    = ((this::class.java.genericSuperclass
        as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>).kotlin
```

Answer (score 1):

the JVM forgets the type of the generic `T` in `BaseDao<T: Any>()` at runtime, which is why type inference fails. A solution to this could be to pass the KClass of T in the constructor of BaseDao:

```
open class BaseDao<T: Any>(val kClass: KClass<T>) {
    ...
}
```

After this, give your reified function an argument that accepts a `KClass:

```
private inline fun <reified T: Any> getCollection(val kClass: KClass<T>):  MongoCollection<T> {
    return MongoDb.getDatabase().getCollection<T>()
}
```

I'm unaware of a method to do this without passing the `KClass` as a argument to the function, but this should work, as the generic `T` can be derived from the provided kClass. 
`

Another way would be to make all methods in BaseDao inline function with reified generics and dropping the generic on the class.

```
open class BaseDao() {

    inline fun <reified T: Any> get(id: String): T? {
        return getCollection().findOneById(id)
    }

    inline fun <reified T: Any> save (entity: T): T {
        return getCollection().save(entity)
    }

    inline fun <reified T: Any> delete(id: String) {
        getCollection().deleteOneById(id)
    }
    ...
}
```

This way the generic `T` can be derived since the method calling `getCollection` is also reified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your parameter `kClass` passed in `getCollection` method is not used at all. Is it normal? And I would avoid the second way because I need to override other methods from `BaseDao` but using `inline` is only on `private` or `final` members.

Answer (score 1):

(For KMongo 4.0.+) no need to use reified generics for the each method, instead this base class can be used as as a starting point:

```
open class BaseDao<T: Any>(
    protected val collection: CoroutineCollection<T>
) {

    suspend fun get(id: Id<T>): T? {
        return collection.findOneById(id)
    }

    suspend fun save(entity: T): UpdateResult? {
        return collection.save(entity)
    }

    suspend fun delete(id: Id<T>) {
        collection.deleteOneById(id)
    }
}
```

And implemented in the particular DAO, say `SessionDao`:

```
class SessionDao(collection: CoroutineCollection<DbSession>) 
      : BaseDao<DbSession>(collection)
```

*(note: inheritance can be replaced with delegation by using `by` keyword if one feel better this way*

This and other dao can be created via DI or some sort of *dao factory*:

```
class DbInstance(mongodbConnectionString: String = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject") {
    private val connectionInfo = ConnectionString(mongodbConnectionString)
    val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine
    val db = client.getDatabase(
        connectionInfo.database ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("mongodb connection string must include db name")
    )


    val sessions = SessionDao(db.getCollection())
}
```

---

Notes:

1. This example is for the coroutine based kmongo, it can be easly converted to blocking kmongo by replacing `CoroutineCollection` to `MongoCollection`
2. I assume documents id's are annotated via Id container which helps to mitigate errors, so documents should be created in this fashion:

   ```
    data class DbSession(
        @BsonId
        val id: Id<DbSession>,

        val name: String,
    )
   ```